# Cannot find "Package Explorer" view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened a project in Eclipse, but found that I cannot switch to the package explorer by clicking *Window->Show View*.  In the menu shown under *Show View*, I just could not find the item "Package Explorer".  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Not all view are listed directly in every perspective ... choose:

```
Window->Show View->Other...->Java->Package Explorer
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also, note that after Window->Show View->Other, you can just type "Package Explorer" in the search bar at the top and it will find it for you.

Answer (score 8):

**The simplest, and best long-term solution**

> Go to the main menu on top of Eclipse and **locate Window next to Run** and expand it.

```
 Window->Reset Perspective... to restore all views to their defaults
```

It will reset the default setting.

Answer (score 7):

Try Window > Open Perspective > Java Browsing or some other Java perspectives

Answer (score 4):

For Eclipse version 4.3.0.v20130605-2000. You can use the Java (default) perspective. In this perspective, it provides the Package Explorer view.

To use the Java (default) perspective:
Window -> Open Perspective -> Other... -> Java (default) -> Ok

If you already use the Java (default) perspective but accidentally close the Package Explorer view, you can open it by;
Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer (Alt+Shift+Q,P)

If the Package Explorer still doesn't appear in the Java (default) perspective, I suggest you to right-click on the Java (default) perspective button that is located in the top-right of the Eclipse IDE and then select Reset. The Java (default) perspective will show the Package Explorer view, Code pane, Outline view, Problems, JavaDoc and Declaration View.

Comment: This worked .. " I suggest you to right-click on the Java (default) perspective button that is located in the top-right of the Eclipse IDE and then select Reset. "

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Window > Show View > Package Explorer
```

it will display the hidden 'Package Explorer' on your eclipse IDE.

• 'Window' is in your Eclipse' menubar.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in debug mode. If this is the problem, you can simply click on the "Java" button (next to the "Debug" button) in the upper-right hand corner, or click on "Open Perspective" and then select "Java (default)" from the "Open Perspective" window.