# Eclipse - return excluded java file back to the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

After I exluded java file from the ***build path*** by ***right click on the file > build path > Exclude*** , I want to return back this file to the build path .

The only way I got that was by edit the `.classpath` file and omit the required file from the `excluding` attribure  , and the make refresh .

Any other better way  ?

I using **Version: Indigo Service Release 2** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click your project and select `Buildpath -> Configure Buildpath` and select `Source` tab.
Open your source folder which had the excluded file, under it you should see in the Excluded area the file which is exlcuded, just remove it using the `Remove` option.
See the image[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the project and use the menu option:

```
Build Path->Configure Build Path->[Source Tab]
```

Select the excluded file from the "Excluded" section and click *Remove*.

Comment: there is no such option in the exluded file  . see my eclise version in the post  .

Comment: I use the same version. The option is available in the `Package Explorer` view.

Comment: OK . note that if the `Package Explorer' is not availabe you can find it by by do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141245/cannnot-find-package-explorer-view-in-eclipse") .

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the exclude entry in the build path options of your project.

```
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source
```